Find the minimum of $m$
Write down the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, 2022$ on the board. You can remove two random numbers $a$ and $b$ from the board and replace them with $|a - b|$. Continue this process until there is only one number left on the board, called $m$. Find the minimum value of $m$.
I tried to find the way for m to reach the minimum value. First, remove $(1,2)$, then remove $(3,4) $and so on until the 1011th moves, where we remove $(2021,2022)$. After the 1011th moves, we have $1011$ numbers $1$. Starting from here, we choose two consecutive numbers from right to left and remove them, obtaining the sequence $1, 0, 0, ..., 0$.  Continuing this way, in all subsequent rounds, the sequence will be $1, 0, ..., 0$. Finally, there'll be only one number remain $1$
But I need to prove that $m\ge1$. Any hints?

This question looks familiar to me. Where did you find it?

"First remove $(1,2)$, then remove $(2,3)$..." but $2$ was removed.  You can not choose $(2,3)$ since there is no $2$.  You mean $(3,4)$ here.

@JMoravitz yes, i mean $(3,4)$. Edited!

Suppose that, at moment $n$, numbers on the board is $a_1, a_2, a_3,...,a_k$. Let $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_k$. At moment $n+1$, we remove $a_i$, $a_j$ and replace with $|a_i-a_j|$ so
$$S_{n+1}=S_n+|a_i-a_j|-(a_i+a_j)$$
Noting that $|a_i-a_j|$ has the same parity as $a_i+a_j$ so $S_{n+1}$ has the same parity as $S_n$. This means that each time the operation is performed, the parity of the sum of the numbers on the board remains unchanged. First, the sum is $1+2+...+2022=1011.2023$ is odd so the final remaining number $m$ will also be odd. Thus $m\ge1$

Noting that $a-b$ has the same parity as $a+b$ we see that this operation can't change the parity of the total sum,  which is odd.
